# How to make animation end when the mouse outside of the common block?

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

When I move the mouse over the text block "services-right" the animation is triggered and the text moves to the right. When I move the cursor to the "about-us--services__button" button the text goes back to its position to the left.

How to make  so text it does not move to the left when the cursor is on the button, and just went back to the left position when the mouse cursor is outside the block of text and button?

**(run code sniped to see what i mean)**

**the text should not move to the left when I hover the mouse over the button, it should move to the left if it is outside the button and text area**

```css
.servicies-right {
  margin-top: 70px;
}

.about-us--services__text {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  right: 34%;
  top: 180px;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in;
}

.about-us--services__text:hover {
  transform: translateX(10%);
}

.about-us--services__title {
  float: right;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.about-us--services__button {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 30px;
  padding: 25px 50px 25px 50px;
  background: none;
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  transition: color 0.25s ease;
  border: 3px solid #383736;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.about-us--services__button:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #383736;
  transform-origin: left;
  transition: width 0.25s ease;
  z-index: -1;
}

.about-us--services__button:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}

.about-us--services__button-title {
  position: absolute;
  right: 40px;
  bottom: 12px;
}

img {
  max-width: 150px;
  min-width: 150px;
  min-height: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
}

.servicies-right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="servicies-right">
  <div class="about-us--services__text">
    <span class="about-us--services__title-desctription">Test title text first</span>
    <br>
    <span class="about-us--services__title">Test subtitle</span>
  </div>
  <img src="https://24tv.ua/resources/photos/news/201805/961055.jpg" alt="test" class="move-img">
  <button class="about-us--services__button"><span class="about-us--services__button-title">Abcdfeghrf</span></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another `transition` to the element with a speed of 0 seconds, so the "enter" animation occurs at 0.6 seconds and the exit at 0 seconds:

```css
.servicies-right {
  margin-top: 70px;
}

.about-us--services__text {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  right: 34%;
  top: 180px;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in;
}

.servicies-right:hover .about-us--services__text {
  transform: translateX(10%);
}

.about-us--services__title {
  float: right;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.about-us--services__button {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 30px;
  padding: 25px 50px 25px 50px;
  background: none;
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  transition: color 0.25s ease;
  border: 3px solid #383736;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.about-us--services__button:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #383736;
  transform-origin: left;
  transition: width 0.25s ease;
  z-index: -1;
}

.about-us--services__button:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}

.about-us--services__button-title {
  position: absolute;
  right: 40px;
  bottom: 12px;
}

img {
  max-width: 150px;
  min-width: 150px;
  min-height: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
}

.servicies-right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="servicies-right">
  <div class="about-us--services__text">
    <span class="about-us--services__title-desctription">Test title text first</span>
    <br>
    <span class="about-us--services__title">Test subtitle</span>
  </div>
  <img src="https://24tv.ua/resources/photos/news/201805/961055.jpg" alt="test" class="move-img">
  <button class="about-us--services__button"><span class="about-us--services__button-title">Abcdfeghrf</span></button>
</div>
```

Comment: it's dosent work, when I move the mouse over the button my text moves off to the left

Comment: you'd like the text to move to the right on hover, then stop animating and remain at that position when the cursor leaves the button?

Comment: the text should not move to the left when I hover the mouse over the button, it should move to the left if it is outside the button and text area